# Как в js принято писать логические условия?

Tags: javascript

Я привык писать так -

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

if( array.length > 0 ){}

var obj = {};

if( obj != undefined ){}
```

И не пишу сравнение только в том случае, если свойство представляет тип boolean.
Но раз слышал, что в js не принято писать так, как в коде выше. Это правда?

Comment: Очередной вопрос ни о чем.

Comment: Эм, @vas, я, безусловно, люблю драму, но, пожалуйста, не надо эскалации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё-таки отвечу.
Да, есть такая штука в каждом сформировавшемся языке программирования - coding convention, которая описывает предпочтительное форматирование кода, и, иногда, разбор частых паттернов. Чаще всего это просто документ, однако в нем описывается самый базис, а, кроме документа, есть еще и негласные соглашения. Итак, зачем она нужна?

- Когда команда девелоперов работает над одним проектом, переход от одного форматирования к другому вызывает фрустрацию (иначе не назовешь). Несмотря на то, что это простое психологическое явление и для победы над ним необходимо простое усилие воли, зачастую оказывается проще обговорить правила заранее. Эта внутрипроектовая конвенция может не иметь ничего общего с конвенциями "за бортом", как, например, замечательный документ от вордпресса, описывающий ровно противоположное PSR.
- Когда ты понимаешь, что работаешь ты один, но у тебя есть привычка а) постоянно менять свое форматирование, просто не следовать единому стилю и даже не иметь его и б) беситься, когда тот стиль форматирования, с которым ты работаешь, не соответствует твоему текущему настроению и погоде за окном. По большому счету, это тесно пересекается с первым пунктом.
- И, конечно, OSS. Опенсорс - это восхитительная и свободная штука, но она реально работает только в том случае, если все возможные разношатания отсекаются. При разработке OSS либо ты пишешь непопулярную штуку, либо следуешь конвенции проекта (а т.к. круг девелоперов не ограничен, и они могут присоединиться в любой момент, и им бы до ужина пулреквест написать, а не с правилами добавления кода знакомиться - конвенция проекта по факту приравнивается к конвенции всего языка в целом), либо в коде начинается (извините, мне правда очень стыдно) ужас, с которым никто не хочет сидеть и разбираться, и проект очень быстро тухнет.

Таким образом, при работе в одиночку можно использовать то форматирование, которое нравится. По своему опыту скажу, что пересаживаться на общую конвенцию оказалось легче, чем я думал, и дополнительным плюсом будут всякие настроенные на эту конвенции утилиты по анализу кода, которые подскажут, где чего не так, бонусом будет распирающая гордость за то, что каждая скобка в коде выверена идеально. Но, опять же, при персональной разработке можно хоть писать код справа налево, переворачивать и выполнять eval'ом - все равно никто никогда не увидит.

Что до динамически типизированных языков с нестрогим сравнением - я лично предпочитаю все то, что правильно скастуется в булеан оставлять кастоваться в булеан. Это занимает меньше места, разница между операциями будет минимальна, это не заставляет задерживаться на простом if глазами. Что конкретно до JS - тут есть проблема с отсутствием единого общепризнанного стандарта, насколько знаю, обычно обращаются к [стандарту](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml), выложенному гуглом. Он [довольно однозначно](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Tips_and_Tricks#Tips_and_Tricks) предписывает не проверять тип, если проверяется общая *провальность* переменной. В случае, если пустая строка, - это все равно наличие ввода, а null - это ненайденный источник ввода и вообще его отсутствие, тип (или конкретное значение), конечно, проверять надо.
У меня всё.

Comment: @Etki, Спасибо! Пусть, кто-то считает, что вопрос не достоин существования, но для меня он очень важен, так как хочется не просто писать код, а писать его с хирургической точностью. Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ и отдельно спасибо за ссылку на конвенцию.  
С понятием конвенция я знаком и даже читал для других языков, но в памяти не отложилось, что я могу найти в ней ответ на этот вопрос. Теперь уж точно навсегда запомню.

Comment: Глаз остановился на коде с циклом 

    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0, paragraph; paragraph = paragraphs[i]; i++) {
  doSomething(paragraph);
}

Comment: Конвенция циклов от google, это все же для детей. Разница времени выполнения кода между правильным и неправильным вариантом, более чем в пять раз, в пользу неправильного варианта.

Comment: @vas, там же написано, что в *некоторых* браузерах NodeList использует итератор и там же в *некоторых* браузерах .length пересчитывается каждый раз. В реальности, конечно, все не так, ради мифической неоптимальности движка *некоторых* браузеров в итоге получаем деградацию.

Comment: Этот пример из конвенции, а скорость я мерил в node.js и свойство length выносил из цикла.

Comment: @vas, ну, во-первых, конвенция обеспечивает удобную работу с кодом, а не его производительность. Во-вторых, с точки зрения сложности алгоритма это вообще одно и то же - скорее всего, содержимое цикла будет явно перевешивать затраты на его работу. В-третьих, это всё проблемы *самого языка*, это не программист должен писать так, чтобы языку было удобно, а наоборот, язык должен быть удобен для использования. Подобное только выделяет те места, которые необходимо оптимизировать.